# How to change the color when the row is unselected in the primeNg p-table?

Tags: css, angular, sass, primeng, p-table

I am trying to change the color of the row to a different color upon row unselect. This feature is something that is provided by the primeng theme. I am trying to override it to customize it.  Is there anyway I can change the row color when it is unselected and then keep the color until that row is selected again?
I am working with single selection p-table here.

I tried this to override:

```
data-table p-table .ui-table.ui-table-hoverable-rows .ui-table-tbody > tr.ui-selectable-row:not(.ui-state-highlight):not(.ui-contextmenu-selected):hover {
   background-color: #2F96B4 !important;
}
```

But this would only change the color on hover over.

And this is what i have for when the row is selected:

```
data-table p-table .ui-table .ui-table-tbody > tr.ui-state-highlight {
   background-color: #007ad9;
   color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this css style will change row and select row color
style.css

```css
p-table .ui-table-tbody > tr:not(.ui-state-highlight):not(.ui-contextmenu-selected) {
   background-color:orange !important;
}

p-table .ui-table .ui-table-tbody > tr.ui-state-highlight {
   background-color:green !important;
   color: #ffffff;
}
```

you can use custom class if you don't want this style to effect all component

```css
.light.ui-table .ui-table-tbody > tr:not(.ui-state-highlight):not(.ui-contextmenu-selected) {
   background-color:lightblue !important;
}

.light.ui-table .ui-table-tbody > tr.ui-state-highlight {
   background-color:lightyellow !important;
   color: #555 !important;
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablebasic-demo-tn1znl?file=src/styles.css)